# mssql replication storage

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, hardware-raid, windows-server-2003-r2

I have 2 boxes. One is dell (4x146GB 15k 3.5'' SAS in raid 10). this is primary sql server (runs only mssql). dell has 8gb ram and mssql is running fine. Dell has windows 2008 R2 x64
second is hp dl360 g5 (2x36gb[raid1] 10k sas for system and 2x700gb[raid1] for storage)
700 gb drives are seagate ST9750420AS. Hp has windows 2003 R2 x64.
Booth servers have mssql 2005 x64

Second server is for sql replication (in transaction mode),wsus, kaspersky adminkit and terminal server for 3 users. 
Hp server has 6gb ram and SmartArray E200i - this is the pain, because they do not support 6 drives. i was planned to use 4x700 gb in raid 10 (for performance)

So, in case, that E200i doesn't suport 6 drives, my plan is that put sql replication to 700 gb array. And question no 1 = how good that will be?
Option to by new controller and cable not acceptable. I have already 4x700 gb drives. But theses drives are standard drives and not enterprise. HP server is second server and that not critical. 
And question no 2: did theses drives affects performance for primary mssql server?
because latency and access times is much higher for non enterprise disks. 
In plan also is to change one drive after half year (in case to booth drives doesn't fail at same time)

Or better way is to sell theses 4 700gb drives and get 2 SAS drives?

Database size:

```
DatabaseName Logical_Name   Physical_Name                   SizeMB
-------------------------------------------------------------------
FTGWIN       FTGWIN_data    D:\MSSQL_FTGWIN\FTGWIN.mdf      6216
FTGWIN       FTGWIN_log     D:\MSSQL_FTGWIN\FTGWIN_log.ldf  11535
```

Thanks. And happy christmas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have terminal server clients accessing a server that is running SQL Server replication related tasks for an important DB, especially a server that only has 6GBs of RAM.  Get rid of the terminal services on this server and whatever RAID you decided on should be fine with only ~18GBs to replicate.

If you need to stick with this server, at least double the RAM and do a 4 x 146GB SAS 15K (RAID10) and everyone should be happy.  If those three users need to have more disk space do a RAID5 or maybe 300GB SAS 15K drives instead.